# Server Error in Application. An error occurred during the parsing of a resource

Tags: asp.net

```html
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Online_Index'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Online_Index" Codebehind="Index.aspx.cs" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Source File: /login/Index.aspx    Line: 1 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34248
```

this is the error i am getting.. my application uploaded on Godaddy.
I don't know much of about asp dot net..

this website was working fine on other server. 
Other Service Provider give me entire backup of website.. and i uploaded on the godaddy.. now facing this issue. please do let me how can run this application like earlier

Comment: What kind of deployment it is? are you deploying without publish or published one?

Comment: you have to give permissions to the folder on godaddy

Comment: Hello @IMAD i  just uploaded all the files on subdomain ( domain/login)  and imported sql file through SQL management.

Comment: Hello @Manraj thanks for reply.. for which folder should i ask to Godady.. ??

Comment: make sure that Index.aspx.cs file is present in the folder that contains Index.aspx.

Comment: first make sure that  Index.aspx.cs file is present in the folder that contains Index.aspx.

Comment: Both files are available in login folder..

Comment: means you have to give permissions on login folder where index page resides

Comment: How can i do this ??   in main folder both index are available.. when i open it .. it has URL for redirect         using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Online_Index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Online/Default.aspx");
    }
}


this code running in index.aspx.cs file

Comment: Many are facing this problem.The issue is from Godaddy. You should contact them

Comment: thanks for revert @manraj  Please do let me know what should i ask to Godaddy ??

Comment: Hello @Manraj i talked with Godaddy they are saying this is Scripting Error .. what should i do now ??

Comment: try build the project and then upload it. and use the option override if source is newer in filezilla. May it help\